# Where can I find a list of tournaments to participate in?

Tags: tournament, fide

Where should I look for a list of tournaments in which new players can participate? I know that many players want to play real matches, but don't know how and where.
Also provide list for online tournaments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For US tournaments, I recommend checking the U.S. Chess Federation (USCF) website:

http://www.uschess.org/tlas/upcoming.php

For non-US tournaments, I would check the FIDE website:

http://www.fide.com/calendar/tournaments.html

http://www.fide.com/calendar.html

Comment: You should also check for local clubs or organizations in your area. I live in the US, but my state and a club in the state capital each have website which post local tournaments. The bigger ones should show up on USCF, but there may be local regular events that do not.

Answer (score 3):

For european events - http://chess-calendar.eu/
Includes non-FIDE tournaments.

Answer (score 1):

For online, redhotpawn.com has tournaments (although you need to pay a yearly subscription (around 50 USD) to be able to participate on them, otherwise you can just play informal games). These are mostly email games.

Also chess.com has tournaments, you also need to be a subscriber there (here you can play both realtime & by email).

[chesscube](http://www.chesscube.com/) site also conducting various online tournaments with different time limits.

Answer (score 1):

For US tournaments (both rated and unrated ) the most updated site:

http://wheretoplaychess.info

Comment: It should be noted that to find tournaments there one needs to go to the "Calendar" page - link near the top left as I type this.

Answer (score 0):

I travel a lot (mainly in Europe and US for work) and I find it difficult to find local tournaments abroad.

I use https://vesus.org/ in Italy to find tournaments.

It's a free web app where organizers can publish their tournaments, collect registrations and share results and standings (using whatever pairing system they prefer just by generiting a file and uploading it).

What is used abroad? Where do you find tournaments? Why not using more of Vesus?

Comment: Is this website something you are connected with? Spam is not allowed here. If this is your website then you need to declare your affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

Both for World and European tournaments: https://www.worldchesscalendar.com

Lists many countries, both FIDE and not, nice UI. Data is updated twice a week, new countries are being added actively.

PS. Yeah, I do develop this website for over a year now and I'm sure it's the best tournaments aggregator in terms of data/interface ratio around there right now. So it's a serious answer to the question